# Get statistics on how ReadyBoost is being used by Windows

Tags: windows, readyboost

I have experimentally started using a flash drive for ReadyBoost. There's no blinking light on it so I don't even know if it's being accessed at all.

Is there some way to get statistics on how often or how well Windows actually uses the drive to improve performance? Something like numbers of cache hits/misses or something...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The most comprehensive information might be obtained using the built-in Performance Counters (which are probably being accessed by 3rd party tools like RBMon).

Simply launch the Performance Monitor (accessible via Management in the Control Panel or simply by typing "Performance" in the search box in Start Menu, it should then be among the results) and add counters. You can select the whole category ReadyBoost Cache by selecting it and clicking Add or you can pick desired counters from within the category and add them to the list.

The most interesting stats might be the Bytes cached, Cache reads, Hit read bytes and Total read / write stats. Your mileage my vary.

Answer (score 4):

There is a program, [ReadyBoost Monitor](http://area-71.net/rbmon/),  that give statistics on how much data is in the cache, how much it is compressed by and how much data has been read from or written to the cache.  I used it for a short while some time ago and it fulfilled my needs.

[image: ReadyBoost Monitor]

Comment: Looks nice but didn't work on Windows 7 64

Comment: Doesn't work in Windows 7 32-bit either. :(

Answer (score 1):

From [this website](http://help.lockergnome.com/vista/Readyboost--ftopict41518.html)

> To see if it's reading/writing from
>   the cache open the Reliability and 
>   Performance Monitor. From the start
>   orb type the first few letters of 
>   Reliability. Click on the entry that
>   pops up at the top left. Once opened 
>   expand the Disk section and order by
>   Write. Look for file labeled `<Drive 
>   Letter>:\ReadyBoost.sfcache.Letter>:\ReadyBoost.sfcache`

Another way is to compare you hdd disk statistics with and without ReadyBoost enabled. This should give you a rough idea on whether or not it is reducing disk access (and hence probably system performance)

Comment: Typing Reliability opened another program. The exact name of the tool is Resource Monitor.

Comment: Start > Run > resmon